# New to Xcode and getting Expected identifier or '(' error

Tags: ios, objective-c

The error is occurring on the fifth line. Any help is appreciated.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface NRViewController : UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *titleLabel;
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)sender;
{
    self.titleLabel.text = @"HelloWorld";
}
@end
```

Comment: Please note that this has nothing to do with `xcode IDE`. Please be careful when using this tag, just because you are developing with `xcode` doesn't mean you should use the tag.

Answer (score 1):

You've put your implementation code in your interface file. Change to :

`NRViewController.h` file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface NRViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *titleLabel;

- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)sender; // Declaration of method

@end
```

`NRViewController.m` file

```
#import "NSViewController.h"

@implementation NRViewController 

// Implementation of method
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(UIButton*)sender
{
    self.titleLabel.text = @"HelloWorld";
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot implement body method in interface file (.h) you should move it to implementation file (.m).
Move that:

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)sender //Remove semicolon from here
{
self.titleLabel.text = @"HelloWorld";
}
```

To NRViewController.m file between

```
@implementation NRViewController
```

and

```
@end
```

If you want to expose this method to other classes leave:

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)sender;
```

in NRViewController.h file.

Comment: I think you have them mixed up, the interface file is the .h and the implementation is the .m can you correct.

Comment: Thought it was a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

It's a syntax error. You have a semi-colon at the end of this line:

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)sender;
```

and it's followed by an opening brace:

```
{
    self.titleLabel.text = @"HelloWorld";
}
```

When you get an error, don't automatically panic and think it's specific to Xcode, or iOS, or Objective-C.